# Clearing a value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I thought this was the syntax to clear out the value but its still present

```
document.getElementById("themapdirectionsaddress").value = '';
```

I am trying to hide the text below the map, i know the element is a class but i changed it locally to an id to test and still nothing

From I-4 take exit 104 Sanford/17-92. Head south on 17-92, note Lake Monroe will be on your left. Regatta Shores is approximately 1.5 miles ahead on the right.

Comment: Your call is correct, can you post the markup for element in question?

Comment: Please provide a link to a page where this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax presented in your question is correct, here is an example of it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/pwC8v/

The page you link to doesn't load for me.

Note that `value` applies only to `input` elements.

Other elements may be cleared with `innerHTML = ''`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried innerHTML?

```
document.getElementById("themapdirectionsaddress").innerHTML = '';
```